# Initialize variable of derived struct type in compile time in c++

Tags: c++

I have the next structs:

```
struct B
{
   int a;
   int b;
};

struct D: public B
{
   int c;
};
```

I want to initialize some variable of struct D in compile time, like if I would initialize the struct B it would looks like:

```
B b1 = { value_of_a, value_of_b };
```

I tried to do this in next ways, but it didn't compile:

```
D d1 = { { value_of_a, value_of_b } , value_of_c };
D d2 = { value_of_a, value_of_b , value_of_c };
```

If I change the struct to:

```
struct D
{
   B bb;
   int c;
};
```

it compiles with "d1" and "d2" initialization.

So, the question is how I can initialize the derived struct?
And if there is now rule for initializing derived struct, what is the reasons?

Thank you.

Comment: Please just use [**Member Initialization list**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor/8523361#8523361) in C++.

Comment: But that list goes to a constructor method. OP is asking how to set the values outside a constructor, i.e. for a single instance instead of all the instances.

Comment: What is the real objective here?  Are you concerned about the initialization time?

Comment: Exactly, I need to initialize it outside the constructor in compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Your `D` that derives from `B` isn't an aggregate (because it has a base class), so you can't initialise it using the aggregate initialisation syntax. You need to use a constructor and initialisation list.

Comment: See this link (for Visual C++)   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0s6730bb%28v=vs.71%29.aspx